# Providing functional interceptors without providing HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient-interceptors

There is now new method of providing `HttpClient` as `provideHttpClient` function. This also can take `withInterceptors()` function to define interceptors.

I have shared module as a separate dependency that defines few interceptors but does not import `HttpClient` (I leave it to applications themselves). As using `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` thing is marked as "can be phased out in future", is there any way to provide functional interceptors without importing whole `HttpClient`? Something like adding `withInterceptors()` to `providers` array.

I can't actually provide array of interceptors as module itself takes crucial required config that is then used by interceptors. Additionally module also exposes bunch of services so it's more comfortable to just import one module.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible and this is not wishable !

> This was a deliberate design choice of the new API; interceptors are
> sensitive to ordering and the registration of the HTTP services to
> actually consider those interceptors, so the API was designed such
> that both ordering and the registration is determined in a single
> place.

Interceptors should be define in a single point to ensure the predictability of their order.

So if you have a lib, you will have to export/expose them.

For more info, look at [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/51539).